# Java Spring: How to handle HTTP Status 400?

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to handle a HTTP Status Error 400. I think that this occurs due to a type mismatch.
So e.g. 

`http://localhost:8080/app/info.htm?id=123` works while 
`http://localhost:8080/app/info.htm?id=abc` doesn't.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "id")
public String getInfo(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, Model model) {
    // get info object via service and show it
    // model.addAttribute("infoObj", infoObj);

    return "info";
}
```

Is there a way to handle this and return e.g. the page `index.jsp` if this error occurs?

Comment: Capture `id` using `Object`

Comment: Okay, that could be a way, but I think that this would be very inelegant because basically you could do this at every controller mapping using never inherited classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand that 400 error  is that The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. That means id works good with int but not strings.

It does have the way that allows you to redirect the page to a certain page if error happned.

you need do some configs in web.xml file. you can do as follows:

```
<error-page>

    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: After restarting the server several times, this worked for me now , thank you!